# Add marker dynamic and dont re-render map?

Tags: react-native-maps

im making map in react native using react native maps and geolib. I have an array of coordinate with only 5 location. When `onRegionChangeComplete` run , function `isPointInside` will check the region is inside of array or not , if false add more location to array of location . But i have an issue, it re-render the map. How can i load more location as marker without re-rendering ?